# updating multiple columns in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
$sql="UPDATE streams SET name='$name', limit='$limit', desc='$desc' WHERE id='$id'";
```

when I run this I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit='15', desc='dsfds' WHERE id='14'' at line 1

where am I going wrong? I have been trying different options but I am not really getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have to escape your limit (and desc) column, its a reserved keyword

```
$sql="UPDATE streams SET `name`='$name', `limit`='$limit', `desc`='$desc' WHERE `id`='$id'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a lot of reserved SQL words as column names. escape them using   `` ` ``

```
$sql="UPDATE streams SET `name`='$name', `limit`='$limit', `desc`='$desc' WHERE id='$id'";
```